# Javascript Displaying screen-wide version from thumbnail image onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a set of thumbnail images which I want, upon clicking one, to display nicely a screen-wide version of it, greying the rest of the site, until another click is made.

I have seen a few website doing it but have not been lucky for the past few days.

I do use HTML Bootstrap (for the time being anyway) for this website and therefore use jQuery as well.

I am sure there is an easy way to do so but Javascript is just not my language and I seem to not be good at searching for it ^^'

In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use jquery plugin like fancybox for it. Please find this link for reference. http://fancybox.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very popular plugin is lightbox.

### Sample

**Step 1:** [Download](http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/assets/bootstrap-lightbox.zip) the javascript file and put the javascript and css in your page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--- boostrap goes here --->
    <script src="bootstrap-lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-lightbox.min.css">
</head>
<body>
   <!-- page content --->
</body>
</html>
```

**Step 2:** Define a div container containing the "big" version of your image.

```
 <div id="myLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class='lightbox-content'>
        <img src="myBigImage.jpg">
        <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>Your caption here</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Step 3:**
Put a javascript in your thumbnails image tag

```
<img src="myThumbnail.jpg" onClick="$('#myLightbox').lightbox()"/>
```

### More Information

- [Bootstrap - Lighbox](http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/)